# enable system apps like camera and calculator by default in fully managed devices android management api

Tags: android, android-management-api

we are using android management API  and developing our own EMMconsole and after provisioning android devices with fully managed devices:- https://developers.google.com/android/work/requirements/fully-managed-device
system apps like camera gallery etc are blocked or hidden by default. we founded a solution for that is to specify package names under the policy for each app like the camera and set its installType to PREINSTALLED but as there are many manufacturers like Oppo, Xiaomi, Samsung and each comes with their own pre-installed apps with different package names so is there is any way we can set system apps to be enabled or preinstalled by default by setting something like a boolean value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me !!

After generating enrollment token add this to generated qrCode object

```
"android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_LEAVE_ALL_SYSTEM_APPS_ENABLED" : true
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, currently there is no way to pre-install apps with different package names for different device brands. However, we have filed a feature request on your behalf but there is no guarantee when this will be worked on.

I suggest joining the [Android Management API mailing list](https://developers.google.com/android/management/release-notes) to keep you posted on the latest updates.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done using "delegatedScopes".

```
"delegatedScopes": {
          "description": "The scopes delegated to the app from Android Device Policy.",
          "items": {
            "enum": [
              "DELEGATED_SCOPE_UNSPECIFIED",
              "CERT_INSTALL",
              "MANAGED_CONFIGURATIONS",
              "BLOCK_UNINSTALL",
              "PERMISSION_GRANT",
              "PACKAGE_ACCESS",
              "ENABLE_SYSTEM_APP"
            ],
```